# Line up very large image and additional text on one page

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

I am building a print layout for Laravel dompdf without CSS and JS frameworks.

```
    <div id="content">
        <div id="plot">
            <img src="{{ $imgData }}" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="info" id="itlm">Some text</div>
        <div class="info" id="dd">{{ $timestamp }}</div>
    </div>
```

I want #plot and the image it contains to take up 100% of the width and 90% of the page height and be horizontally centered. Both #info-divs should take up the remaining 10% height and both have 50% width.

My problem is that I can't fit everything on the first PDF page. Either the additional text is overlapping with the image or it is pushed on an empty page.
I am passing base64-encoded PNG data to my controller function which is loading the custom print-layout and returning the PDF via dompdf. The PNG-data is very large in width and height.

My amateurish CSS looks like this:
I changed it very often so it is a big mess.

```
    @page {
        size: A3 landscape;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #plot {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
    }

    .info{
        display:block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        font-family: Sans-Serif;
    }

    #itlm{
        text-align: left;
    }

    #dd{
        text-align: right;
    }
```

I think my understanding of CSS is too limited to solve this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `max-width: 842px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to your #content. It will center the image and the text will be under the img. Good practice to put in your CSS the `*{border: 1px solid black};` (it will give a border to every content on your site just you can see how is your layout, and when you're done with the site you just remove it. Hope it helped.

Comment: Didn't work. The picture is much larger thna 842px and thus destroys the PDF layout. I solved the problem by switching from dompdf to laravel-pdf (mpdf wrapper) and using footers.